# Is there any way to turn hints off in Lego Marvel Superheros?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

In the previous Lego games there's always been the option to turn hints on or off.

They're on by default in Marvel Superheros game, and I can't find any option to turn them off. It's also no longer just text popping up like in the previous games, it's Agent Colson telling me to do things, and it's getting old fast.

Did they really remove the option to turn hints on/off? Is there a cheat code, difficulty setting, or hack I can use to remove the hints? How do I shut Agent Colson up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 100%'ed the entire game, seen every cheat code, unlocked every vehicle and character, and I've not found a way to turn the hints off.  Agent Coulson still reminds me that red-white-and-blue-sparkling, Captain-America-shield-shaped switches can be activated by throwing Captain America's shield into them.

I don't believe there to be a way, sadly.